# How can I select all input of type 'file' by jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Select just by type, every element, <input type="file" name="userfile" >

---

```html
<input type="file" name="userfile" >
```

Comment: Have you attempted any research into this? Take a look at the jQuery API in the 'selectors' category: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors, specifically you're looking for the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Also, given that jQuery largely implements CSS selectors, take the time to read the [CSS Selectors Level 3 documentation, at the W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow please refer this before asking question - > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With this code you can select an input with type "file":

```
$('input[type="file"]')
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use the `:file` pseudo-class selector:

- as a stand-alone `:file`

  ```
    $(":file")
  ```

or

- on an `input` type: `input:file`

  ```
    $("input:file")
  ```

**Example:**

```js
$("input:file").css('background', 'lightgreen');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all elements by type 'file' like so:

`$('[type="file"]')`

Ref.: *[Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)*